# How to make REST calls secure

Tags: javascript, json, security, rest

I'm calling a webservice using the REST methodology using JSON/JS/jquery and am wondering if there is a way to call the webservice without exposing my API keys in the source code. Anyone know of a way to hide the API keys from the public and still make the call?

I'm worried that if someone goes through my source, they will be able to use my API key.

Comment: Is there reason your API requests need to happen from the browser/client?

Comment: so the page renders then makes the call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could delegate the calls to your own server, so instead of:

1. Browser sends HTTP request to external REST API, with API key
2. External REST API sends response to browser

you have

1. Browser sends HTTP request to your server
2. Your server sends HTTP request to external REST API, with API key
3. External REST API sends response to your server
4. Your sever sends response to browser

---

I'm not sure that someone else "stealing" your API key is a huge problem, though, since API keys (Google, for example) are frequently associated with specific domains.

Comment: +1. Proxying is probably a good solution here, although I doubt there's a problem to begin with.

Comment: @cfarm I wouldn't say that. What makes you think so? You're just proxying requests, not changing the semantics or structure.

Comment: because SOAP is already on the backend? that way instead of server->browser->server->service->server->browser, it's only server->service->server->browser

Comment: @cfarm I don't think that SOAP has anything to do with it. You're sending REST requests to **third-party** APIs. If you use your server to proxy REST requests from the browser, it's really simple for the browser to ask the server to request a third-party URL. SOAP is just not needed for this, much heavier weight, and really not the right tool for the job. But like I (and others) have said, is protecting your API key really a concern?

Comment: @cfarm (in light of the edit to your comment) is the web service you're calling a REST or a SOAP one? I don't see why `server → service → server → browser` couldn't be done with REST. I also don't see how it relates to the browser at all. If the server makes a web service request independently of the browser, but uses that data to send whatever information to the browser, the browser wouldn't care at all where the data comes from ...right?

Comment: I have a choice to use REST or SOAP

Comment: I have a choice to use REST or SOAP. If I use REST on the backend, that would be fine, but my point is why parse the returned json when you can already get it in object notation? in any case, my criticism to your answer for using REST would be 1. when the browser sends the HTTP request to my server, what prevents the user from doing the same with the url that I'm using in the .getJSON call and 2. if you're going to call a 3rd party service using REST from the backend, why not use SOAP since SOAP returns objects?

Comment: @MattBall One thing that I'm missing is that: by using your proxy (step 1) anyone could potentially create a page that accesses data on your behalf, using you API key. Or do you have a way for your proxy to ensure where the request is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to send the API keys to the client, and have them be usable, and not have them be exposed.  What you more likely want is to have a translation layer, where you allow external (non-validated) clients to make requests against an exposed endpoint, then you use some sort of logic to validate the request, then pass through the request.

API keys are typically for your use as a partner, not for distribution; this is the way to avoid distributing them.